# Applying for a UK visa with a Schengen visa that is about to expire. Would this cause issues?

Tags: schengen, uk, visa-refusals

I am planning to travel England in next December(20-27th). But my current Schengen visa is valid till December 31st. I am not sure, if my visa application will be refused because of that?I have not found any clear information in gov.uk site. They only mentioned, I need to have valid visa when I travel.

Comment: The UK is not part of the Schengen Area. You cannot enter the UK with just a Schengen visa, you need a UK visa.

Comment: Yes I know, so my question is, is there any possibility to get refused to get British VISA considring my current situation?

Comment: No, this is completely unrelated. You can get a UK visa without having ever had a Schengen visa.

Comment: Your UK visa application will not be refused because of your Schengen visa.  It will also not be accepted because of your Schengen visa.  Rather, it will be refused or accepted because of the weakness or strength of the application.

Comment: What will you do on after the trip? Leave the EU immediately? Return to the Schengen area for a couple of days and then leave? Apply for another status or find a way to extend your stay? If you plan on leaving, having evidence of that might help a bit. On the other hand, if you are in a position to obtain another status and remain in the Schengen area after December, then evidence that you have applied for it could be useful.

Comment: Actually, My problem is: My Schengen VISA will end on 31st December, I will start my VISA extension procedure on first week of December, But I will have to start my British VISA application before that, so British Embassy will not able to know, I am extending it. Obviously I will comeback to Germany as I have work here. But How can I solve this situation?

Answer (score 7):

You want to apply for Standard Visitor Visa and you have a Schengen that will expire about two weeks after you arrive in the UK.

> so my question is, is there any possibility to get refused to get
>   British VISA considring my current situation?

Yes, those are delicate situations and they are not going to be happy about it. It looks like you want to remain in Europe after your Schengen expires and are using a UK visa as a pretext to advance a secondary agenda.  Maybe you are, maybe you're not, but that's what they will think.  They are paid to think like that.

They will also be wondering why you did not extend your Schengen and more importantly what is making you *apply for a UK visa at this particular time* (that can be a show-stopper).  You need to get proactive and address both of those in your application BEFORE they have a chance to start worrying about it.

In a more general sense, they usually like it when the applicant has a Schengen currently or in their history.  It means the applicant has already performed in a regulated environment (that's a good thing).  But the timing of the application in your case is suspect and hence elevates the risk of refusal. So be diligent and proactive.

Comment: Actually, My problem is: My Schengen VISA will end on 31st December, I will start my VISA extension procedure on first week of December, But I will have to start my British VISA application before that, so British Embassy will not able to know, I am extending it. Obviously I will comeback to Germany as I have work here. But How can I solve this situation?

Comment: The answer is above, perhaps reading it again will help?

Comment: @VessilliZayetsev you can apply for a new Schengen visa up to three months before your intended travel.  If you apply for a visa for a trip on January 1st, you can lodge that application at the beginning of October.  But really, a lot depends on your trip.  If you are traveling to the UK from a non-EU country, then you should not have too hard a time dissociating your trip from your Schengen visa.  If you are traveling to the UK from a Schengen country, it will be harder.